# Is it possible to trigger / bind a jQuery UI event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, events, callback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery AutoComplete Trigger Change Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431459/jquery-autocomplete-trigger-change-event)

I am using jQuery UI v1.9 and I successfully implemented the [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete) widget. I would like to know if it is possible to trigger / bind a jQuery UI event and, if so, how to make that. That is, for example, if I have

```
$('#autocomplete_field" %>').autocomplete({
  change: function (event, ui) {
    // Make something...
  },
  minLength: 2,
  ...
});
```

is it possible to run the jQuery UI `change` event by binding that to a `keypress` event?

---

*Note*: I tried

```
$('#autocomplete_field').bind('keypress', function(event) {
    $('#autocomplete_field').autocomplete('option', 'change').call();
});
```

but I get the following error (from the Firebug console):

```
TypeError: elem.nodeName is undefined
...ks = jQuery.valHooks[ elem.type ] || jQuery.valHooks[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase(...
```

Comment: IIRC the events for each jQuery UI widget were prefixed with the widget name.

Comment: Why do you use `$` for one selector but `$jQ` for another?

Comment: @zzzzBov - I don't understand what you mean (*BTW*: what is IIRC?!). Can you be more explicit?

Comment: @wirey - I updated the question. My fault.

Comment: you realize that autocomplete already fires anytime that textbox is changed??

Comment: you don't need all that binding to events, its like you're trying to make your own autocomplete when jQuery UI already did the work for you

Comment: @Scott Selby - I am trying to trigger the `change` event even on other events. Probably, user1827044 and zzzzBov get the idea...

Comment: I get it, it looks like some good suggestions have been  offered

Comment: @Scott Selby - Thank you, anyway! ;-)

Comment: you could always have .autocomplete  ,  and another delegate in another spot for .change() - the .change() will cover keypress and autocomplete select method

Comment: @Scott Selby - Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will cover autocomplete for the textbox:

```
  $(".autoCompleteTxtBox").autocomplete({
                 source: "www.url.com/Source",
                 select: function (event, ui) {
                     //something to do when user selects from dropdown
                 }
             });



 $(document).on('keyup, keydown, change', '.selectorClass', function(event){    
       //I'm not sure what you need ui for exactly
      var pos = $(this).position(); // gets position of .selectorClass
      var val = $(this).val(); // gets current value of .selectorClass
      var width = $(this).width(); // gets width
     // if there are multiple '.selectorClass' - $(this) is the one that fired event
   });
```

Does that give you an idea of how $(this) is used ?

a little redundant to handle events in 2 spots for same textbox , but if that's what you want - this will have a functioning autocomplete , and another place for handeling everytime the textbox is change no matter how it was changed.

Comment: I tried your code but it seems do *not* fire the `change` event every time text box is changed (in your example, on `keyup`, `keydown` , ... events).

Comment: @Backo - edited - that should cover it all for you

Comment: actually use .on() - edited answer , version 1.9 can handle .on()

Comment: I have to pass `event` and `ui` arguments to `function()`, as well as for the jQuery UI `change` event makes. Is it possible by using your code?

Comment: function(event) will definitively work , function(event, ui) should  work ,  you can always use $(this)  as well

Comment: anywhere in the function $(this) can be called and it refers to the element that fired the event

Comment: I tested `function(event, ui)` this way `$(".autoCompleteTxtBox").on('keyup, keydown, change', function(event, ui){ ... }` and it does *not* work: I get `TypeError: ui is undefined` when I call the `ui` variable inside that function. What is the problem? How should I use `$(this)`?

Comment: *BTW*: I need the `ui` variable because I would like to *check if an item is or not selected from the jQuery Autocomplete menu* (see also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456321/how-to-handle-cases-when-no-item-selection-is-performed-but-a-string-is-present)).

Comment: you may want to figure a better way to make use of select: function part of the autocomplete , that is fired when a user selects from the dropdown , or maybe you could do .blur() of textbox and see if the val() matches any of the returned values from autocomplete,

Comment: It is hard to figure out how I can use the `select` event in order to reach the behavior I am looking for... so, a solution I thought of, is to use the `change` method and some callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick review of the [jQuery UI source](http://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.js), I was mostly correct in my initial guess (it's been a while since I've used any jQuery UI widgets).

`autocomplete` and the like use the `jQuery.Widget` builder, which prefixes any events called with the name of the widget (or `widgetEventPrefix` if one was provided).

For `autocomplete`, this means that the events should be triggerable and bindable via `autocompletechange`, `autocompleteclose`, etc (you can find the rest of the events on the [`autocomplete` widget's documentation page](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/))

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easy if you just abstract the function out of your autocomplete.

```
$('#autocomplete_field" %>').autocomplete({
    change: function (event, ui) {
        changeFunction()
    },
    minLength: 2,
          ...
});

$('#autocomplete_field').bind('keypress', function(event) {
    changeFunction();
});

function changeFunction() {
//make something
}
```

Comment: How can I pass `event`, `ui` arguments to the `changeFunction()` function from `$('#autocomplete_field').bind('keypress', function(event) { changeFunction(); });`?

Comment: Edit changefunction so that it takes arguments, so function changeFunction(event, ui) { //make something }.  Then call it with changeFunction(event, ui).